# How would one create variables using lapply?

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I have so many subdatasets in the list and so listing each dataset would be cumbersome and very tedious. Is there a way to achieve this using either `lapply` or `purrr`? Thanks in advance.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- list(data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")),
  data.frame(
    A = c(10, 21, 30),
    B = c("Test10", "Test24", "Test32")))

names(mydata) <- c("dat1", "dat2")


mydata$dat1 <- mydata$dat1 %>% 
  mutate(id = "dat1")

mydata$dat2 <- mydata$dat2 %>% 
  mutate(id = "dat2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
listNames <- c("dat1", "dat2")
names(mydata) <- listNames
mydata <- lapply(
            listNames,
            function(x) {
              mydata[[x]] %>% mutate(id = x)
            }
          )
names(mydata) <- listNames
mydata
$dat1
  A     B   id
1 1 Test1 dat1
2 2 Test2 dat1
3 3 Test3 dat1

$dat2
   A      B   id
1 10 Test10 dat2
2 21 Test24 dat2
3 30 Test32 dat2
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution can be to use `Map`, i.e.

```
Map(function(x, y)transform(x, id = y), mydata, paste0('dat', seq(length(mydata))))
```

Comment: Magnificent! This would be very applicable when the names follow a given set of pattern. Wondering aloud when I have some names such `gooddata`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with `lapply`,

```
invisible(lapply(seq(mydata), function(x) mydata[[x]]['id'] <<-names(mydata[x])))
mydata
```

gives,

```
$dat1
  A     B   id
1 1 Test1 dat1
2 2 Test2 dat1
3 3 Test3 dat1

$dat2
   A      B   id
1 10 Test10 dat2
2 21 Test24 dat2
3 30 Test32 dat2
```

Comment: Not sure I’d happy to maintain code that uses gratuitous side-effects inside higher-order functions: it’s unexpected and makes it harder to keep track of what’s happening. Most casual readers of such code would expect the function being passed to `lapply` to be pure, i.e. not have side-effects.

Comment: I don't understand your point. What is the side-effect in here? Using `<<- ` ?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: Well, Actually I use `<<-`  whenever I need in my daily coding. If it works, then it is good! This is my perspective.  I have never considered it as a side-effect before. But I will think about your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case for `purrr::imap`.

If `mylist` is already named:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# if `mydata` is already named:
imap(mydata, ~ mutate(.x, id = .y))

#> $dat1
#>   A     B   id
#> 1 1 Test1 dat1
#> 2 2 Test2 dat1
#> 3 3 Test3 dat1
#> 
#> $dat2
#>    A      B   id
#> 1 10 Test10 dat2
#> 2 21 Test24 dat2
#> 3 30 Test32 dat2
```

If `mydata` is not already named we can also use `imap`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mydata <- list(data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")),
  data.frame(
    A = c(10, 21, 30),
    B = c("Test10", "Test24", "Test32")))


imap(mydata, ~ mutate(.x, id = glue::glue("dat{.y}")))
#> [[1]]
#>   A     B   id
#> 1 1 Test1 dat1
#> 2 2 Test2 dat1
#> 3 3 Test3 dat1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    A      B   id
#> 1 10 Test10 dat2
#> 2 21 Test24 dat2
#> 3 30 Test32 dat2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a like a good time to use `imap` which is useful for handling names of lists:

```
purrr::imap(mydata, ~mutate(.x, id = .y))

# $dat1
#   A     B   id
# 1 1 Test1 dat1
# 2 2 Test2 dat1
# 3 3 Test3 dat1

# $dat2
#    A      B   id
# 1 10 Test10 dat2
# 2 21 Test24 dat2
# 3 30 Test32 dat2
```